# Insert certains columns from tableA to tableB - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two temporary tables

```
#tempA
 colum1      |   colum2   |   colum3
-------------+------------+----------+
        0001 | NULL       |05/10/2022|
        0002 | NULL       |06/10/2022| 
        0003 | NULL       |07/10/2022|
```

#tempB

```
#tempB
 dato1       |   dato2    |  
-------------+------------+
             |            |
             |            | 
             |            |
```

I want to insert the values on  colum1 and colum3 from #tempA into to #tempB(dato1,dato2)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you used the same data types:

```sql
INSERT INTO tempB
SELECT colum1, colum3 FROM tempA;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'INSERT INTO SELECT' statement:

```
INSERT INTO #tempB(dato1, dato2) 
SELECT colum1, colum3 
FROM
#tempA
```